# Pagination with Avro File

Tags: java, pagination, deserialization, avro

I am trying read data from a Avro File file stored in HDFS. Now so far I am able to read the entire data by using `DataFileReader` or `DataFileStream`.
Now I want to implement pagination. Is there any specific way to do it ?

I have already gone through their basic documentations and as per my understanding I think this can be done by using Synchronization Marker.
I have tried by :

```
SeekableInput seekableInput = new AvroFSInput(dataInputStream, 5);    
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
    DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(seekableInput, datumReader);
    fileReader.seek(startOffset);  // set to the start-offset
    while (fileReader.hasNext() && !fileReader.pastSync(endOffset)) {
          GenericRecord gr = fileReader.next();
          System.out.println(gr);
    }
```

But this code giving me a :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:210)
    at com.globalids.test.AvroTest.deserializeWithPageing(AvroTest.java:112)
    at com.globalids.test.AvroTest.main(AvroTest.java:45)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid sync!
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.nextRawBlock(DataFileStream.java:293)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:198)
    ... 2 more
```

I have also tried setting sync interval during data writing process. Also tried to call sync() method after each record is inserted to the file using `DataFileWriter`.
Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong ?

> Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call sync() instead of seek() if startOffset is not from valid position in file :

```
SeekableInput seekableInput = new AvroFSInput(dataInputStream, 5);    
DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader = new DataFileReader<GenericRecord>(seekableInput, datumReader);

**fileReader.sync(startOffset);**

while (fileReader.hasNext() && !fileReader.pastSync(endOffset)) {
    GenericRecord gr = fileReader.next();
    System.out.println(gr);
}
```

Comment: This code did work. At-least it's not giving me any exceptions. But still the records I'm getting are from very start of the file. What I wanted to do is: 
If my startOffset is 5 then I want fileReader to start reading from record number 5. So that I can jump into any record whenever I need for Pagination purposes. Can you please suggest me any idea ?
And thank you very much for you previous answer.

Comment: Avro does not support seeking to a record, but does support seeking to a block. And each block tells you how many records are in it, so you can work out how to get to a specific index that way.